# Basic "for" loop vs cmder

Tags: bash, for-loop, cmder

My loop's syntax:

```
for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done
```

Error:

```
Unexpected i at this time.
```

Is there something wrong in my head and I can't see I'm messing up the syntax or is Cmder just bugged?

> Cmder is updated to the latest version (updated just now)
>   Running on win 10

Comment: script works for me when running it with bash.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know I'm not blind. Just a cmder thing then..

Comment: Isn't `Unexpected var at this time` a batch error?

Comment: cmder != bash. the default cmder window runs cmd, Windows trusty and rusty basic command line. You can have bash windows under cmder though, using some bash that's installed on your computer, like Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Comment: Just executed `for /l %x in (1, 1, 100) do echo %x` and worked fine while it shouldn't if it was bash so ye, got it, cmder != bash, so you can't play with it the same way you'd do on a bash shell

Comment: --> Settings --> Startup --> Tasks --> + --> call it bash and make it point to C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~ or something along these lines to create a bash startable via the green +. Optionally, make that the default startup window via --> Settings --> Startup

Comment: I already have a Task called `{bash::bash}`, should I use that one as default shell? Or is it necessary to have that new one you are tlaking about?

Comment: You already have a task called bash, and assuming that it points to a legit bash instance, how did you manage to get into a cmd window?

Comment: Don't know, I'm really new to cmder, could be anything I did wrong without even knowing. Anyways, I found a way of making it to work. Instead of executing the loop directly, I create a bash script and then execute it like so `bash myscript.sh`

Comment: The key fact here is that cmder can open many types of command lines (and do so simultaneously), so once properly configured you can easily open the type of window you need, there should be no need for indirect solutions like calling bash in a cmd window. Maybe you should just play around a bit more with cmder..

Comment: @fvu for sure I will, thanks for the help!